# How to save preferences like firefox?

Tags: c++, c, firefox

I have created a simple browser and I want load preferences from a file like firefox does.

Do I have to load the preferences in the memory or do I have to read each preference when it is necessary ?

Comment: It depends on the situation. You have a choice. Loading the whole file as a unit when the program starts is much faster, but it will also take up memory throughout the program's lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

A common practice is to load the preferences in a data structure in memory.This has many advantages over reading each one when necessary:

- Reading from disk is a very costly operation, very inefficient of a few bytes.
- You will need most preferences at startup, why load them seperately?
- The space consumed by the preferences in **negligible**.
- You save code complexity and possible bugs.
- If you will be loading preferences all the time, you impair the disk driver's ability to process more important requests.